# Please describe to me why we use null(htmlAttributes)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Why would we use `null` (in htmlAttributes) in this below?

If we didn't use it, what would happen?

```
@Html.ActionLink(@movie.Name,"Details","Movies", new {id = movie.Id}, null)
```

Comment: Did you try not using it? Also, can you tell us what the parameter name of that parameter is? The overload I see in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper.actionlink?view=aspnetcore-3.1) has way more parameters so my guess is that it isn't the same method I found.

Comment: object htmlAttributes parameter

Comment: Are you sure it matters? I would still just try removing it altogether and see if it behaves differently. The documentation is ... how should I put it ... *MIA*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`htmlAttributes` are just as simple as the name implies, HTML attributes. For example, if you wanted to give your anchor tag a css class, you could do it by replacing `null` with `new { @class = "btn btn-success", id="xxx" }`. If you use null then no custom attributes would be assigned.